# How can I divide the items of a combo box with a dash or something similar

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radcombobox

I have a RadComboBox that wraps the items if they are longer than the width of the combo box so my combo box would show something like this:

```
All
White T Shirts
Black T Shirts
Blue T Shirts With
Images
Green T Shirts
```

So as you can see Blue T Shirts With Images wraps, which is good this what I want... But now i received a request that this althought it is what they want to see, they would like to see it separated like with a dash underline like this:

```
All
--------------------
White T Shirts
--------------------
Black T Shirts
--------------------
Blue T Shirts With
Images
--------------------
Green T Shirts
--------------------
```

So this what they would like to see or something similar, maybe even like something on the side like

```
* All
* White T Shirts
* Black T Shirts
* Blue T Shirts With
  Images
* Green T Shirts
```

I am not sure how to do this and would appreciate any help as to how to do this.. Right now this is my mark up of the drop down

```
 <telerik:RadComboBox ID="ddlTShirts" runat="server">
 </telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to Change the items template of the control.

```
<telerik:RadComboBox ID="RadComboBox1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk1" Checked="true"/>
            <asp:Label runat="server" ID="Label1" AssociatedControlID="chk1">
                <img src='...' />
            </asp:Label>            
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>
```

Reference: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx

Comment: And how could i do that is there a link with an example you may provide?